# Big ideas and big ways of thinking in statistics?

Tags: st.statistics, teaching

I'm moving to a new university for the fall semester, and I'll be teaching a statistics class for the first time. I'm familiar enough with *doing* statistics (my dissertation in math ed was a mixed-methods study with some quantitative components). However, I've never *taught* it before, so I don't yet have that level of knowledge about key statistics concepts and/or the "right" ways to think about them.

To give you a for-example: When I teach calculus, I know that I want people to leave understanding (among other things) that the subject is really mostly about creating and refining approximations (the limit process; linear approximation; the Riemann sum; etc. etc.).

So, in an effort to bootstrap my understanding a little bit, I thought I'd ask here: What are the big ways of thinking that are really useful for understanding and properly using statistics?

If it's helpful to know, our book is OpenIntro's [Intro Stats with Randomization and Simulation](https://www.openintro.org/stat/textbook.php?stat_book=isrs).

Thanks in advance!

(FYI, I've crossposted this to /r/math.)

Comment: I like to approach statistics as the answer to Hume's Problem of Induction.

Comment: @CraigFeinstein I'm intrigued! Say more!

Comment: see my question and also my answer: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/39545/what-are-the-critiques-of-the-we-might-as-well-assume-it-solution-to-the-probl

Comment: If you don't get enough useful answers/suggestions here, perhaps try http://stats.stackexchange.com

Comment: Bayes versus frequentist.  (And Bayes is the proper way... when conditions are met.)

Comment: In my opinion, the most important thing to realize is that when you'd be interested in $P(A|B)$, statistics (disappointingly, but also inevitably) only gives you $P(B|A)$. Typical example: A: Madame X is not a psychic; B: at most $k$ out of $n$ coin flips were predicted correctly

Comment: This seems especially important because the usual terminology attempts to obfuscate matters. For example, if a test rejects a hypothesis at significance $5\%$, then that does of course not mean that this decision was correct with probability $0.95$.

Comment: Spencer, as for statistics being the answer to Hume's Problem of Induction, we cannot know if nature is uniform, but if it is, then using statistics is the best strategy to make predictions about nature.

Comment: A course for which kind of students? Students in mathematics? Students in psychology?... First year, second year,....?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I believe it is mostly first year students, and a wide variety of majors.

Answer (score 3):

If a student walks away understanding the distinction between an **estimand**, an **estimator** and an **estimate**, along with the idea of a **sampling distribution**, you will have done an above average job. Equipped with these concepts, it should be clear that one must evaluate estimators based on how well they perform on average, in some relevant sense (such as coverage or mean squared estimation error).

On a more personal note, I favor de-emphasizing testing and especially cook book recipes for statistical tests --- it encourages missing the forest for the trees and arguably is not especially relevant in many applications.

Answer (score 2):

The American Statistical Association has resources for statistics education, available here:

http://www.amstat.org/asa/education/home.aspx

...including, in particular, resources for undergraduate education.

Perhaps the "Guidelines for Assessment and Instruction in Statistics Education (GAISE) College Report" (available under the "Guidelines and Reports" heading) might be helpful. Oh, here is a direct link, why not:

http://www.amstat.org/asa/files/pdfs/GAISE/GaiseCollege_Full.pdf

This report seems relevant for your question because it lists 9 "big" goals for students. From there you can follow up to get more detail about those goals; recommendations for how to help students work toward the goals; pointers to further resources; etc. Good luck!